# Obtain Square Card Nonce From Backend

Tags: php, wordpress, square, square-connect

I'm building a website in which I need to process credit card payments via **Square**.

In order to process payments, I need to get a card nonce from Square.

My question: is there a way to get card nonce from Square using PHP  without using JavaScript?

Comment: I don't know square api, but I would be surprised if this wasn't severely hindered. Giving out card details to any backend is not secure.

Comment: ok,thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

No, you must use the Square provided card payment form (that uses JavaScript) to create a card nonce. There is no other way to generate a nonce.